# merge two json side by side with comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have this simple json which i want to stack side by side.

```
    var data11={type: "line",name: "Original Size",minimum: 1,dataPoints: [{x: 1,y: 155},{x: 2, y: 55}]};

   var data22= {type: "line",name: "Compressed Size",minimum: 1,dataPoints: [{x: 1,y:12},{x: 2,y: 35}]};
```

i tried extend but did not work

i want my result to be like this

```
 {type: "line",name: "Original Size",minimum: 1,dataPoints: [{x: 1,y: 155},{x: 2, y: 55}]} ,{type: "line",name: "Compressed Size",minimum: 1,dataPoints: [{x: 1,y:12},{x: 2,y: 35}]}
```

you can see that i added comma when i combined. i tried several things but all are merging inside as well however i just want my data to stack side by side with comma in between them

i tried these many things but noone is stacking

```
//var jsons = new Array();
//jsons.push(first_json,second_json);
//jsons.push(second_json);


 var jsonArray1 = {'name': "doug", 'id':5};
var jsonArray2 =  {'name': "doaaug", 'id':52};
//jsonArray1 = jsonArray1.concat(jsonArray2);
 var newObj = Object.assign({}, datavaluee, kutta)



 var topData = {
    "auth": "1vmPoG22V3qqf43mPeMc",
    "property" : "ATL-D406",  
    "status" : 1,
    "user" : "test001@aaa.com",
    "name" : "Abraham Denson"
}

var bottomData = {
    "agent" : "pusher@agent.com",
    "agency" : "Thai Tims Agency",
    "agentCommission" : 1000,
    "arrival" : "arrive 12pm at condo",
    "departure" : "leaving room at 6pm",
}

var completeData = Object.assign({}, topData, bottomData);

console.log(completeData);
```

Comment: What you want doesn't make sense. You can't have two JSON side by side, but you can put them into an array: `newObj = [jsonArray1, jsonArray2]`

Comment: `Object.assign merges the two objects into a single object.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't "extend JSON" and those two things you mentioned are not "JSON", they are JavaScript Objects.

JSON stands for "JavaSript Object Notation", and this is what they are: you have two objects that you need to put together, "separated by a comma".

So, what you really need is an Array.

```
    var data11={type: "line",name: "Original Size",minimum: 1,dataPoints: [{x: 1,y: 155},{x: 2, y: 55}]};

   var data22= {type: "line",name: "Compressed Size",minimum: 1,dataPoints: [{x: 1,y:12},{x: 2,y: 35}]};
```

There are several ways to create an array, one of them is:

```
var myArray = [];

myArray.push(data11);
myArray.push(data22);
```

You can see for yourself that when you `marshal` or write that array into JSON, it will automatically insert the comma you wanted.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```